# Can __all__ be list of objects rather than strings?

Tags: python

I found myself using the following pattern in the `__init__.py` files:

```
from tool.shed import shovel
from tool.shed import bucket

__all__ = [shovel, bucket]
```

The code like that works will all python versions that I have ever tried, but it seems that this is an accident. I have not seen it mentioned anywhere that `__all__` can be a list of objects (rather than strings), and also, this is reported as an error when running `mypy`:

`Type of __all__ must be "Sequence[str]", not "List[object]"`

Is there any reason why `__all__` should be list of strings? Or are objects ok too?

Comment: The reason why `__all__` should be a list of strings is that it only works when it's a list of strings. The reason it should be a list of strings is because that's how [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) says it works, and it works the way the documentation says. Non-strings are not OK because they aren't strings. The reason strings are required is that not all objects have an inherent name: if you say `[shovel, bucket]` you get the *values* of those names, and there may not be any way to get the names back from the values.

Comment: @jwodder Sorry, it indeed is. I should have searched more carefully :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will break `from mymod import *` by doing this. `__all__` isn't used otherwise.

```
>>> from a import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1019, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _handle_fromlist
TypeError: Item in a.__all__ must be str, not module
```